# How prove this inequality with $\sqrt{a_{1}+\sqrt[3]{a_{2}+\sqrt[4]{a_{3}+\cdots+\sqrt[n+1]{a_{n}}}}}$

Tags: inequality

> let $a_{i}>0,i=1,2,\cdots,n$, show that
>   $$\sqrt{a_{1}+\sqrt[3]{a_{2}+\sqrt[4]{a_{3}+\cdots+\sqrt[n+1]{a_{n}}}}}\ge \sqrt[\displaystyle{(2!+3!+4!+\cdots+(n+1)!)}]{a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n}}=(a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n})^{\displaystyle\frac{1}{(2!+3!+4!+\cdots+(n+1)!)}}$$

Maybe this can use AM-GM inequality to prove it?

it is clear when $n=1$ is $=$.

when
$n=2$,it is prove this follow
$$\sqrt{a_{1}+\sqrt[3]{a_{2}}}\ge\sqrt[\displaystyle2!+3!]{a_{1}a_{2}}=\sqrt[\displaystyle8]{a_{1}a_{2}}$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow a_{1}+\sqrt[\displaystyle3]{a_{2}}\ge\sqrt[\displaystyle{4}]{a_{1}a_{2}}$$
let $\sqrt[\displaystyle12]{a_{1}}=x,\sqrt[\displaystyle12]{a_{2}}=y$
so $$\Longleftrightarrow x^{12}+y^4\ge x^3y^3$$
since
$$x^{12}+y^4=x^{12}+\dfrac{y^4}{3}+\dfrac{y^4}{3}+\dfrac{y^4}{3}\ge 4\sqrt[\displaystyle4]{\dfrac{1}{3^3}}x^3y^3>x^3y^3$$

But for general How prove it? I have try Mathematical induction,and also is failure.can you  help?

Comment: How about using AM-GM inside out in a similar manner?